# Rails simple_form_for creating multiple entries from one input field

Tags: ruby-on-rails, simple-form-for

**The problem**

[Screenshot of Stackoverflow tags field](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BYfJQ.png)

Similar to the tags field on Stackoverflow when you add a question, I would like to add an input field for users to add comma-separated tags when they create new projects.

[Simplified DB schema](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rTHJ6.png)

`projects > project_tags (join table) < tags`

If a tag does not exist, it would be added to the `tags` table, then to `project_tags` to link the project itself.

If the tag already exists, it would simply be linked by adding a connection in `project_tags`.

**Code**

```
# new.html.erb
<%= simple_form_for @project do |f| %>
  <%= f.input :name, label: "Project name" %>
  ...
  <%= f.simple_fields_for :tags do |t| %>
    <%= t.input :tags %>
  <% end %>
  ...
<% end %>
```

Comment: You really want to look into using AJAX here instead to both lookup the existing tags and to create new tags on the fly as it will give a much better user experience and be a lot less hacky then anything constructed with nested attributes.

Comment: Would you have a recommendable resource to share on ajax with rails?

Comment: https://medium.com/lightthefuse/adding-autocomplete-suggestions-to-an-input-field-in-a-rails-application-with-webpack-b2a840a65087 the second part is really just sending a POST request to `/tags.json` and then updating the form with the returned ID.